# How to use pear without installation

Tags: php, pear

I am developing a script for a site using php and I want to use some PEAR classes as they are very helpful to save me from some repeated tasks.

The Problem is that I have to deliver the project as a standalone folder that will be placed in an existing website without depending on any server configuration other than PHP 5 and MySQL.

So I am looking for an easy way to do that. Can any one help?

Answer (score 6):

You can download the packages (be sure do download any dependencies as well), and put them into a directory.  Then, in php, [adjust the include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to include that directory:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mypear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Then, you can use pear just like normal (`include Mail.php;`)...

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the Pyrus installer: http://pear2.php.net/

It allows you to do this exact thing, multiple PEAR package installs in different locations.

$>php pyrus.phar install /Path/to/project/lib pear/Net_URL

where lib is a directory within your project.  The main issue I ran into is while the docs say it's for 5.3+ you need 5.3.1.

- http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.php
- https://pyrus.com/en/help/tasks/getting-started

Comment: The link for pyrus.com has nothing to do with PEAR packages at all.  You can see more info at http://pear2.php.net/PEAR2_Pyrus